# Get Elements, (children) of React.element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I'm having an issue I would like to resolve, Maybe someone has an answer for it.

My problem is that I have a Component that has its own Views and Components, at the same time I have a Parent Component thats using the this specific Component.

I want to check if the child of the Child Component has some props.

Child Component

```
const Child = () => {
    return (
        <View wantedArgument={true}>
            <View anotherWantedArgument={false}>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Parent Component

```
const Parent = () => {
    return (
        <Child>
          
        </Child>
    )
}
```

So I want to get the props values of the child views.
I can use useRef for those Views, but it's not that generic and dynamic.

My question is, is there a way I can get those elements of the child?

Thanks ahead
Eden.

Comment: I wonder how you can do it with a useRef, because I pretty sure you can't. There is no relation between component props and their HTML representation.

Answer (score 0):

You can check props of `Parent`'s children using `React.Children` API.

In this example, we checking the props of every `Parent`'s child and logging them.

If you want to go to a deeper level (Child of Child of Child etc.), do it with [recursion](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Recursion) with inductive step `child.props.children` (if available).

```
const Child = ({ prop }) => {
  return <>{prop}</>;
};

const Parent = ({ children }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    React.Children.forEach(children, child => {
      console.log(child.props);
    });
  }, [children]);
  return <div>{children}</div>;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Parent>
      <Child prop={1} />
    </Parent>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit distracted-cerf-sq4j1]